# Insert and update in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Here i have to update the table as follows,

My table looks like,

```
| subject | Type | Gender | s1 | s2 | s3 | s4 | s5 | s6 |
| sub1    | 1    |  M     | 10 | 20 | 0  | 0  | 0  | 0  |
| sub1    | 1    |  F     | 11 | 22 | 0  | 0  | 0  | 0  |
| sub1    | 2    |  M     | 30 | 40 | 0  | 0  | 0  | 0  |
| sub2    | 1    |  M     | 50 | 60 | 0  | 0  | 0  | 0  |
    .
    .
    .
| subn    | 2    |  F     | 500 | 600 | 0  | 0  | 0  | 0  |
```

here i have another table 2,

```
| subject | Type | Gender | s1| s2| s3 | s4  | s5 | s6 |
| sub1    | 1    |  M     | 0 | 0 | 11 | 16  | 25 | 30 |
| sub1    | 1    |  F     | 0 | 0 | 12 | 17  | 24 | 29 |
| sub1    | 2    |  M     | 0 | 0 | 13 | 18  | 23 | 28 |
| sub1    | 2    |  F     | 0 | 0 | 14 | 19  | 22 | 27 |
| sub2    | 1    |  M     | 0 | 0 | 15 | 20  | 21 | 26 |
   .
    .
    .
| subn    | 2    |  F     | 0 | 0 | 50  | 60 | 70 | 80 |
```

I need to update the values in table 1 from table 2. Don't look the values it's sample. Note: Extra rows may be less or more in both tables. If the row is not avail in table 1, have to identify and insert that row too in table 1 from table 2. If you need any queries regarding this i am here. thanks in advance.

Comment: do you have a primary key?

Comment: @ FuzzyTree, No primary key in the given table.

Answer (score 4):

You want to use `insert . . . on duplicate key update`.  First, you need a unique key to define duplicates.  Let me assume it is the first three columns:

```
create unique index idx_table_subject_type_gender on table(subject, type, gender);
```

Then you can do what you want as:

```
insert into table1(subject, type, gender, s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6)
    select subject, type, gender, s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6
    from table2 t2
    on duplicate key update s1 = t2.s1, s2 = t2.s2, s3 = t2.s3, s4 = t2.s4, s5 = t2.s5, s6 = t2.s6;
```

Comment: hope it sounds well. i am new to on duplicate method. I will follow the way which you explained. Thanks @Gordon Linoff.

Comment: if we create unique index it wont accept the duplicate values. the data is like that sub1 may be come upto four times and gender should be return more and type too.

Comment: @rk3265423 . . . If you create a unique index (on the right columns), then the `on duplicate key` clause gets invoked, doing an update instead of an insert.  You say "If the row is not avail in table 1", the unique index just consists of the columns that allow you to see if the row is available.

Answer (score 2):

For the update:

```
UPDATE table1
JOIN table2 ON table1.subject = table2.subject AND 
               table1.type = table2.type AND 
               table1.gender = table2.gender
SET table1.s1 = table2.s1, table1.s2 = table2.s2, 
    table1.s3 = table2.s3, table1.s4 = table2.s4, 
    table1.s5 = table2.s5, table1.s6= table2.s6
```

For inserting rows that does not exist in `table1`:

```
INSERT INTO table1
SELECT *
FROM table2
WHERE (subject, type, gender) NOT IN (
   SELECT subject, type, gender
   FROM table1
)
```